# Куда пропал "сумерок"?

Tags: лексика

**Слово "сумерки" в Р.п. имеют две формы:** "сумерек" как основную и "сумерок" в качестве варианта (с небольшой частотностью, скорее всего устаревающего).

Но в текстах встречается  **еще форма с.р. ед. числа "сумерок"**, и вот интересно, когда и почему слово перестало употребляться. И почему форма **именно мн. числа "сумерки"** получила дополнительное значение и стала основной?

Из словаря: СУМРАК, -а; м. Неполная темнота, **полумрак**. СУМЕРКИ,  мн. 1. **Полумрак перед заходом солнца** и наступлением ночи, а также перед восходом солнца.

Примеры:

Обвечерело, **сумерок** опустился, в перелеске галки на сон гнездятся, еще тараторят. [Б. В. Шергин. Из дневников (1930-1960)]

**Сумерок** утренний ― ополоски в небе мутные, так после дождей бывают часы, близкие к утру. [Ник. Никитин. Ночь (1922)]

В канун нового года висел между кресел, вперясь в синий **сумерок**; черный вошел силуэт. [Андрей Белый. Между двух революций (1934)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фасмер
су́мерки
мн. Связано чередованием гласных с др.-русск. **суморокъ** – то же, цслав. **сѫмракъ**, сербохорв. су̏мра̑к, словен. sǫ́mrak, чеш. soumrak, слвц. súmrak. Образовано от *sо̨- и *mьrknǫti, *morkъ. См. смерка́ть(ся), ме́ркнуть, мерца́ть, мо́рок, мрак.

Когда‐то было и единственное число и множественное.
Даль 
. Су́мерки ж. мн. су́мерек м. пск. **су́морок** м. заря, полусвет: на востоке, до восхода солнца, а на западе, по закате, утрение и вечерние сумерки; первые досветки, вторые су́тиски.

Сохранившаяся форма в псковском говоре. И отдельная теперь форма **сумрак**. В корпусе очень мало примеров с вариантом **сумерок**в ед.числе, поэтому можно допустить, что писатели использовали неологизм, опираясь на происхождение слова и используя известное чередование о-е.

Comment: А мне "сумерок" кажется устаревающей,  а не новой формой.  И всё-таки откуда взялось и стало основным мн. число? К примеру, святки - это святы́е, праздничные дни, здесь форма мн. числа понятна.  А какое значение множественности можно найти в сумерках?